# Supporting Native OS APIs from Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, cups, blazor-webassembly

I have an IPP/CUPS library that allows local printing, can i integrate same library from Blazor Web Assembly running in a browser sandbox on Windows? 
In Chrome or Chromebook, it has been supported using Browser extension.
Any feedback is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Blazor is a web page. What you can do with JS in the browser, you can do from a blazor app. If you have an extension that lets you access the OS (hopefully, a *calculated* security risk), you can call these methods through the JS Interop now

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i agree whatever it is possible with JS in the browser that can be possible with blazor. However, .i believe it is different because of C#, .Net Core will be available to most of the platform, C# based web assembly powered with .net core, possibility from browser may change, unless otherwise limitation from web browser, what are the limitations in web browser sandbox?